# How to pass a json file as a value for a key under request body of a feature file

Tags: karate

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJD06.png)I am creating a feature file using Karate framework and as per that i need to pass a json file as key value pair in the request body

eg 
Given url
And def textJson = text1
And request{test:'test1.json',test2:'description text'}
when post
then status 200

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJPkJ.png)

the json file is read into a variable in another feature file and passed on to this feature file.

As of now i am getting the requested file is missing basically its not reading

Comment: try harder to ask clearly, and use proper formatting: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

```
Given url 
And def textJson = text1 
And request{test:'test1.json',test2:'description text'}
```

So if I understand this correctly, you intend to input the data from a json file into the test key under request. You are currently passing in a string instead of actually reading in a file. To read in a json file and save it as a variable try the following syntax.

```
And def test1 = read('test1.json')
And request { test1: '#(test1)'}
```

I am a little confused at some of the other syntax you have included. I can point out a couple other problems in the syntax.

```
Given url #You need to actually have a url after the url keyword
And def textjson = test1  #This does not seem to point to a reference
And request {test: 'test1.json', test2: 'description text'} # The test is not actually reading json in but the string "test1.json"
```

I wasn't exactly sure the scope of this question, but I hope that this helps.